# When opening blender, the left side of the screen is slightly cut off

Tags: 3d-view

Every time I've attempted to open a new blend file, the left side of the screen is slightly cut off. I've tried toggling full screen and resizing the window.

It looks something like this. Oddly enough, the window appears in full with pre-made blend files.
[image]

Comment: I had exactly the same problem ! I simply uninstalled the software then I reinstalled and the bug was gone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse over the header bar that looks cut off and scroll with your mouse wheel. It just has more tabs than fit on the screen.